# White screen is displayed while switching between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-studio, start-activity

When I move from one Activity to another Activity, a white screen is displayed for 2 seconds. I am using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: show your second activity xml and java file.

Comment: Do you have any web services in SecondActivity?

Comment: Amsheer : No server calls. FirstActivity has MoodStock Scanner Camera. Second Activity contains just one Text "hello world".

Answer (score 35):

Create a Theme like this:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="YourParentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Apply this theme to your second activity

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you.

Comment: what this actually do?

Comment: Its delaying activity loading time.

Comment: by adding that line its not taking one click to open the app . It's taking two clicks and after the second click it holds for 2 sec and launches the app

Comment: What if I don't have an activity to implement the style? for example, when i just want to open a new browser from my app. When I back to my app i see the blank white screen....

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
context.StartActivity(intent);

Can you please help?

Comment: @Omtechguy have you tried to apply this style to the first activity when you back to your app?

Answer (score 6):

If your activity contains more complex layouts, do not use `finish()` after setting flag. Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and _TASK` instead and it will solve your problem.This worked for me perfectly

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.l̥FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
startActivity(intent);`

or use simply like below

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't finish your current activity.

Answer (score 6):

While switching from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo, till ActivityTwo onCreate method gets executed default background is shown which is the white/black screen. Good practise is don't do heavy operation in onCreate. To fix the issue set transparent background to ActivityTwo as shown below.

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="YourParentTheme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

In Manifest set above theme

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityTwo"
            android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before calling `startActivity(intent);`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)`

Answer (score 1):

If your activity contains more complex layouts/ contains large size background image it takes rendering, so only that white page is displaying. If you want to remove that time delay use low size png images and clear layout designs.

Answer (score 1):

By using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** you are getting white screen, remove this like use this. It will work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To go to next activity use flag

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what's the intent of finish()?

Comment: to finish() current activity

Comment: I dont want to finish my current(first) activity.

Comment: ok then show your full code..have you added your set conttentview to your second activity?

Comment: sometimes only using this will not work..so better try Youractivityname.this or getApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

use `finish` if you want to clear the activity means when you press back then there is no stack of activity.

So you want to clear then use `finish` otherwise don't use it.